# Firebase query using . equalTo (boolean value, String key) not working

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I’m trying to query my data to retrieve a list of items sorted alphabetically and filtered by those items marked as “visible”.

Here’s my data structure.

```
listItems
    list_1_uid
        item_1_uid
            name: "Item 01"
            nameLowercase: "item 01"
            visible: true
        item_2_uid
            name: "zItem 02"
            nameLowercase: "zitem 02"
            visible: false
        item_3_uid
            name: "aItem 03"
            nameLowercase: "aitem 03"
            visible: true
```

Here’s my query.

```
mQuery = mFirebaseDbReference
    .child("listItems")
    .child("list_1_uid")
    .orderByChild("nameLowercase")
    .equalTo(true, "visible");
```

My query returns no data. If I remove the .equalTo(true, "visible") statement the query returns my entire alphabetized list.

Any suggestions on how to retrieve my filtered list?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Queries in Firebase are tied to property specified in the `orderBy` call. Therefore the `equalTo(boolean value, String key)` call in this example refers to `nameLowercase`, so it will query for all items with `nameLowercase` set to `true`. The second parameter refers to the key of the item (e.g. `item_1_uid`) and can be used to specify a starting point in the query. This is useful for paginating through the results for example.

Since there is no limit on this query, a solution would be to use a query that orders by "visible" and then do any additional sorting on `nameLowercase` client side with the final result:

```
mQuery = mFirebaseDbReference
    .child("listItems")
    .child("list_1_uid")
    .orderByChild("visible")
    .equalTo(true);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, helped me a lot